# how to replace null values in dynamic table with 'mean' or 'unknown' as per the column data type in azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, data-migration

I have data from two data sources i.e SQL and PostgreSQL. For every table  want to replace the column having 'Null values' with MEAN if column type is integer and by 'Unknown' if column type is string.
I have tried using derived column but i am not sure how to pass on dynamic column values.
I created a pipeline with the 'LookUp' activity and 'ForEach' activity and calling a dataflow.

The migration is happening from SQL to Postgres so need to validate tables as well null values.

Comment: can you please add expected output in Question.

Comment: The expected outcome in sink  is table with no null values in it.

Comment: In Integer column type nullvalues should replace with string 'Mean' or mean value of column?

Comment: it must be replaced with 'Mean' value of column

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 cases here, the first one is replacing a null values in a string column with 'unknown' and the second case is replacing null values in an integer column with the mean of the values in the same column.

Main idea:

1. add a derived column , replace the null values in a string with unknown
2. fix the null values in an integer column,replace null with zeros so we will replace these zeros with the mean value when we calculate it by using a **window** activity.

Here is a quick demo that i built in ADF.

First, i created a dataset with 3 columns (name,height,address), height type is integer and address is a string like so:
[image]

ADF:
[image]

1. Derived Column activity:
   modified address and height column as mentioned above.
   [image]
2. Window activity:
   in window activity, the idea is to replace the zeros with the mean value, to see the difference, i added a new column named it 'newHeight' just we can see the difference but you can override the original height column
   in window settings -> window columns :
   added a new column newHeight with the value :

   case(height == 0 ,divide(sum(height),count(height)),toLong(height))

[image]

**Output**:
[image]

please read more about window transformation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-window

Comment: Thanks for providing solution.                                                                                                                           Is their any way the above can be done for dynamic table columns?

Comment: ok maybe consider providing a Stored procedure in Source when you pull the data from the SQL DB , in that way you don't really need to do any data transformation in a dataflow.